# Program with extern decl-specifier in a class definition

Tags: c++, declaration, language-lawyer, definition, extern

Consider the following program:

```
extern class A;

int main() {}
```

Is this well-formed according to the c++ standard? If it is ill-formed is diagnostics required? I'm getting different results for different compilers:

- Clang: No compiler errors (only a warning): http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/lhb8XNU01IyVhMnc
- GCC: Compiler error: http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/mIH9qmNY4noI1sEc
- Visual c++: No compiler errors (only a warning): http://webcompiler.cloudapp.net/

Comment: Vendors usually define warnings as diagnostic. It is meaningless to classify compiler messages into errors and warnings (or whatever else a compiler might emit) as far as standard compliance is concerned.

Comment: Yes, you are right, with -pedantic-errors i get errors for both Clang and GCC.

Comment: Clang also provides `-Weverything` whereas GCC does not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The program is ill-formed according to §7.1.1/1:

> If a *storage-class-specifier* appears in a *decl-specifier-seq*, […]
>   **the *init-declarator-list* of the declaration shall not be empty**
>   (except for an anonymous union declared in a named namespace or in the
>   global namespace, which shall be declared `static` (9.5)).